# Working with user directories with directories and glob in rust

Tags: rust, directory, glob

I am trying to learn rust, and my current objective is to be able to locate .js files in the user's documents directory under a subfolder.

I can currently list all js files in said subfolder.

```rust
    if let Some(user_dir) = UserDirs::new() {
        let script_path = user_dir.document_dir().unwrap().join("test").join("**").join("*.js");
        dbg!(&script_path);
        for script in glob(script_path.to_str().unwrap()).unwrap(){
            dbg!(script);
        }
    }
```

This would do nothing in the case where the folder test didnt exist.
How would I go on about handling this case and furthermore create the folder test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This would do nothing in the case where the folder test didnt exist. How would I go on about handling this case

Store the intermediate path and call [`Path::exists`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.exists).

> furthermore create the folder test?

[fs::create_dir_all](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.create_dir_all.html).

Comment: So I have to inevitably do this? no way I could use an error handler? Finally , It seems I would have to unwrap the script variable insise glob, why is that? what error could be thrown?

Comment: "So I have to inevitably do this? no way I could use an error handler?" why would you get an error handler? There's no error to globbing a path which doesn't exist.

Comment: "It seems I would have to unwrap the script variable insise glob, why is that?" wll no, you could handle the error properly

Comment: " what error could be thrown?" https://docs.rs/glob/0.3.0/glob/fn.glob.html glob will return an error if your pattern is not valid.

Comment: so if my above pattern is invalid, would that mean the path doesnt exist?

Comment: No, if the pattern is invalid the pattern is invalid, that's all. The `glob` syntax is pretty simple but it's still possible to have invalid patterns and `glob` surfaces these as error. Looking at the source, possible errors are more than 2 `*` in a row, unclosed brackets, and `**` not preceded or followed by a path separator.